# W3 Total Cache JS and css Minify folder are empty

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-w3-total-cache

When i enable Multisite using subdirectories function and minify file status “404” so my multisite subdirectory not working properly, because minify folder are empty /var/www/html/wp-content/cache/minify/*empty .

Website: https://wahwahyar.com/hindi

```
# BEGIN W3TC Minify cache
location ~ /hindi/wp-content/cache/minify/.*js_gzip$ {
    gzip off;
    types {}
    default_type application/x-javascript;
    add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    expires 31536000s;
    etag on;
    if_modified_since exact;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.13.2";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade";
    add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
}
location ~ /hindi/wp-content/cache/minify/.*css_gzip$ {
    gzip off;
    types {}
    default_type text/css;
    add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    expires 31536000s;
    etag on;
    if_modified_since exact;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.13.2";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade";
    add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
}
```

[image: JS and CSS minify error]
**Helps you. About my server:**

- Nginx
- WordPress Multisite
- Php 7.2
- Cloudflare Full Site Delivery (Cache everything)

Thank you. Let me know your feedback.
Best regards.

Comment: Have the same problem here, did you solve it?